# No controller or keyboard input in RetroArch

Tags: technical-issues, controllers, keyboard, retroarch

I have installed retropie on an old Intel Atom laptop. Controller config is working fine in emulationstation, but if I load anything RetroArch related, I have no controller.

I've seen a few suggestions to remap the keys in RetroArch, but how do I do that if I cannot navigate the RetroArch menus?

I even went as far as running the command manually from the commandline, but still no luck. I just pops up a message that says "Controller not configured"

```
/opt/retropie/emulators/retroarch/bin/retroarch --menu --config /opt/retropie/configs/all/retroarch.cfg
```

Comment: Which controller are you using? You should be able to look up which driver package is available for your controller and install it via the `apt-get`.